# Ghidra Python - Get Decompile Line Text by RVA

Tags: decompilation, python, ghidra

Is there a way in Ghidra Python to get the corresponding decompile line by `RVA`?

Or the opposite - get the corresponding `RVA` from a given line in a decompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how any examples how you could get the line like Ghidra would render it, but as a start you can look at https://github.com/schlafwandler/ghidra_ExportToX64dbg.

The basic idea is to walk the C-AST and extract the ClangStatements that have a corresponding RVA.

This has limitations, namely:

> At the moment the source code export is limited to elements that appear as `ClangStatement` in the `ClangTokenGroup` returned by `getCCodeMarkup()`. This works fine for most variable assignments and function calls, but excludes most control flow altering constructs (like `if`, `for` or `while`).

If you really need the line and not the ClangStatement, my first idea is to search for the Ghidra code that renders the AST, find the part where a line is rendered and extend it to retain a mapping from a line to a list of ClangStatements used in that line. Then you can iterate over the lines and filter for those that use a statement that has the RVA you are interested in.